# Populate Snapshot manager with missing snapshots or revert to one manually?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot, vmware-vmdk

Is there a way to populate the Snapshot Manager with snapshots that are listed in the datastore but not under Manage Snapshots.  Is there a way to either populate Manage Snapshots or using something like vmkfstools revert to the snapshot manually?

Long story short, I had a hardware failure and had to re-add the datastore to the Linux VM.  I believe before the failure that I was using Portal-000003.vmdk but when I try to start the system with that datastore I get the following error: Failed to power on virtual machine Portal. File system specific implementation of LookupAndOpen[file] failed

When I try to using Portal.vmdk it boots up fine, but seems to be running code from 2015.   When I look at the Datastore I have several vmdk files:

```
-rw-------    1 root     root     21308092416 Jun 23  2016 Portal-000001-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           323 Nov 24  2015 Portal-000001.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     117391208448 Nov 24  2015 Portal-000002-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           330 Nov 24  2015 Portal-000002.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root       8192512 Apr 19 05:17 Portal-000003-ctk.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     521604673536 Apr 19 03:28 Portal-000003-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           457 Apr 19 04:35 Portal-000003.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root       8192512 Apr 18 17:37 Portal-000004-ctk.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     32146173952 Apr 17 03:03 Portal-000004-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           398 Apr 17 03:02 Portal-000004.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root       8192512 Apr 19 05:52 Portal-000005-ctk.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     2198843392 Apr 17 03:07 Portal-000005-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           398 Apr 17 03:07 Portal-000005.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root       8192512 Apr 18 17:37 Portal-000006-ctk.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     4413435904 Apr 17 03:15 Portal-000006-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           398 Apr 17 03:10 Portal-000006.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root       8192512 Apr 18 17:37 Portal-000007-ctk.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     31961624576 Apr 17 07:43 Portal-000007-delta.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root           398 Apr 17 07:10 Portal-000007.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root     536870912000 Apr 19 05:57 Portal-flat.vmdk

-rw-------    1 root     root          8684 Apr 19 05:57 Portal.nvram

-rw-------    1 root     root           560 Apr 19 05:56 Portal.vmdk

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            78 Apr 19 05:40 Portal.vmsd

-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          3394 Apr 19 05:57 Portal.vmx

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           367 Apr 18 16:40 Portal.vmxf
```

Any suggestions on what else I can do to revert back to the latest good snapshot?

Thanks.